# Do I have to close my US bank account because I'm leaving the country?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, non-resident

I moved over to the US from the UK with my job but am now moving back to the UK. As I was an HSBC Premier customer I automatically qualified for a Premier Account in the US and didn't have to supply them with a social security number. I would like to keep the checking account open and my credit card, but will I be able to do this if I am no longer resident?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you will be able to keep these accounts open. I have had a UK bank account for sixteen years without living in the country. As littleadv says, watch out for US regulations about reporting foreign holdings.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with DJClayworth: nothing prevents you from keeping a US account.  But some US banks are not very good at providing service to non-residents, especially if they are not US citizens.

As an example, now that I'm a "nonresident alien," my US bank – where I have been a customer for more than twenty years – will no longer accept an instruction for a wire transfer unless I personally sign it in one of their branches.  I have pointed out that as I live three thousand miles away this is not very practical, but they won't change.

I suggest you review the various services that you may need after you leave the US, and talk to your bank to make sure they can provide them.  If you find that you have to change to another bank, do it before you leave.

Comment: I don't think they have a choice on this, I think it's federal law.

Answer (score 4):

See no reason why not. Make sure the UK taxman doesn't care, some countries (US, ahem ahem) require its residents to report foreign bank accounts.

Answer (score 0):

have eperienced hsbc on two countries as well. they do not comunicate.

if you have to bring some document or sign something at the US branch, the UK will play dumb and say they can't accept anything.

and the answer is: you can have bank accounts anywhere in the world regardless where you are from/are at.

all that counts is the tax code for the countries you are obliged to pay tax at. US citizens and residents have to pay tax even if they get a $20 bill as xmas present from their grandpa while living in Finland. you will have to check the law in the UK.

Comment: my experience with HSBC was the opposite - had an account in Singapore that I could access no issues in the US

Comment: My overseas branch will not even call me, they bug me via email so i call them. And that's premier accounts all around. The US branch is a joke, when i'm there, one of the 5 employees can answer questions, the other 4 just stall and waste my time. Maybe I just have to change branches... or find some place where i can complain about that.